# como definir rotas no MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

boa noite..

tenho o seguinte Controller: HomController

com a Action: Login

ao clicar no botão entrar a minha URL fica da seguinte forma:

http://localhost:58379/home/login

gostaria que a URL não fosse apresentada dessa forma, e sim:

http://localhost:58379/bemvindo

já tentei reconfigurar a rota, mas todas as minhas tentativas não deram certo:

```
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            "T",
            "bemvindo",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
        );
```

onde está o meu erro nessa configuração?

eu preciso setar o atributo Rote na minha Controller/Action?

obrigada!

Comment: você pode usar `Route` para passar o nome que você quiser para a sua action, mas para remover o nome da sua controller olhe essa resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948890/5457357), e vê se te atende.

Comment: Ja tentou colocar [Route("bemvindo")] logo acima de sua action Login no Home controller?

Comment: sim.. já havia tentado colocar  [Route("bemvindo")]